# Getting a button to trigger two events

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, jquery-animate, gsap

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I need a bit of help. I am using the [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/) library to animate svg objects and I am running into an issue. I have it set up that if you click on a button, the animation plays out but I want to set it up in a way that if I click on the button again, it reverses the animation. Do you guys have any idea about how to do this? I tried using event listeners but that didn't work for me. Maybe I did something wrong. Please help. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried?

Comment: Yes, please share your code.

Comment: You could also include a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a boolean switch that flips each time the button has been clicked, and trigger different animation according to the boolean value.

For example,

```
var bool = false;
function onClickAnimation() {
  if(!bool) {
    bool = true;
    //play the animation
  } else {
    bool = false;
    //reverse the animation
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe?

```
var bool= true;

    function toggle(){
        if (bool){
            // script for animation 1
            bool = false;
        } else {
            // script for animation 2 
            bool = true
        }
    }
```

Feel free to ask if I'm not clear enough

Comment: That jQuery `.toggle()` method is a bit too specific isn't it? It only works to hide or show the specified element(s), not for any arbitrary animation. (Unless you were thinking of the [old `.toggle()` event handling method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), which was removed from jQuery in v1.9.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example. You can switch out the height property for whatever CSS you want to toggle back and forth. This is called an event delegator. There's only one event listener that does different functions depending on the conditional statement.

https://jsfiddle.net/mqmf12hy/

```
var resizeButton = document.getElementById('resizeButton');
resizeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var happyFace = document.getElementById('happyFace');
  // If the image is small, make it big
    if (happyFace.style.height == '56px') {
    $(happyFace).animate({
        height: '72px'
    }, 1000);
  }
  // If the image is big, make it small
  else if (happyFace.style.height == '72px') {
    $(happyFace).animate({
        height: '56px'
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```